# What is difference between two functions in class returning the same value

Tags: javascript, class

What is the difference between this:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name_of_animal() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const dog = new Animal("Max");
console.log(dog.name_of_animal); // Max
```

And this:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    name_of_animal() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const dog = new Animal("Max");
console.log(dog.name_of_animal()); // Max
```

I've also seen this:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name_of_animal() {
        return this.find_name_of_animal();
    }

    find_name_of_animal() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const dog = new Animal("Max");
console.log(dog.name_of_animal); // Max
```

The last code looks useless, but what 'bout two above it?

Both of codes, first and second, returning the same value.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: None of your codes work because you should be referencing `dog.`, not `Animal.` when calling the instance method. Your third code also does not work because `find_name_of_animal` was not invoked, only referenced

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed it.